# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'str'

Tags: python

Please help me, I cannot see why this isn't working and I have tried everything that comes to mind :)
Seems like the issue is with the print section on line 19.

```
def name():
  name = str(input("What is your name"))
  print("Hello " + name + " Welcome to the hotel!")
  return name
  
def bed_category():
  category = str(input("What category of room would you like? (single,twin,double)"))
  return category
  
def number_of_nights():
  nights = int(input("How many nights will you be staying?"))
  return nights


def total_cost():
  cost = 40 * nights
  if category == "single" or category == "Single":
    cost = 20 * nights
  print(name + ", The total cost for you staying for" , nights , "nights will be £" , str(cost))
  return cost


#Main program
name()
category = bed_category()
nights = number_of_nights()
total_cost()
```

Output:

```
  File "python", line 27, in <module>
  File "python", line 19, in total_cost
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'str'
```

Comment: You need to initialize name, just like your other variables `name = name()`

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `name + ", The total cost for you staying for"` , `name` refers to the `def name():` at the top of the file. If you want to get its actual return value, you could call the function:

```
print(name() + ", The total cost for you staying for" , ...
```

Of course that's just assuming you wanted to use the `name()` function's return value in that case. It appears you actually are trying to get and set variables that are not within the scope of your functions, though, since you also refer to `nights` and `category` when they're not in scope. You should be using a class to store the results, or [globals](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword), or you could restructure your code to pass around those variables like the other answer here.

Comment: This will call `name()` when the output is printed. The OP wants the program to ask for your name first, but this will make the program ask for the name a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Within the scope of function `total_cost` there's no `name` variable declared, so it assumes it's the global function `name` defined in the first line (`def name():`)

A quick solution is to save name to a variable when you call the function `name()`, so that:

```
name = name()
category = bed_category()
nights = number_of_nights()
total_cost()
```

A more elegant solution would be to not use global variables, and so, define each variable as arguments of `total_cost`

```
def total_cost(selected_name, selected_category, selected_nights):
  cost = 40 * selected_nights
  if selected_category == "single" or selected_category == "Single":
    cost = 20 * selected_nights
  print(selected_name + ", The total cost for you staying for" , selected_nights, "nights will be £" , str(cost))
  return cost


#Main program
total_cost(name(), bed_category(), number_of_nights())
```